# application specific lock in iphone

Tags: iphone

is it possible to make an app in iphone which locks other application. for example i want to put a lock on sms application, contacts etc. if anyone knows please reply

Answer (score 0):

The thing which you are asking is not possible.

Apple supports SANDBOX environment , through that any application can not access other application data.

So you cannot stop executing other applications. Unless the device is jailbroken. then cydia supports such kind of applications.

And If you are having enterprise account to manage the enterprise devices , then this thing will be possible.